# How can I add confidence intervals to a scatterplot for a regression on two variables?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I need to create an insightful graphic with a regression line, data points, and confidence intervals. I am not looking for smoothed lines. I have tried multiple codes, but I just can't get it right.

I am looking for something like this:

[image: scatterplot example]

Some codes I have tried:

```r
p <- scatterplot(df.regsoft$w ~ df.regsoft$b, 
                 data = df.regsoft,
                 boxplots = FALSE,
                 regLine = list(method=lm, col="red"),
                 pch = 16,
                 cex = 0.7,
                 xlab = "Fitted Values",
                 ylab = "Residuals",
                 legend = TRUE, 
                 smooth = FALSE)
abline(coef = confint.lm(result.rs))
```

But this doesn't create what I want to create, however it is closest to what I intended. Notice that I took out "smooth" since this is not really what I am looking for.

How can I make this plot interactive?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind switch to ggplot and the tidyverse, then this is simply a `geom_smooth(method = "lm")`:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble( #random stuff
  x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  y = 0.25 * x + rnorm(100, 0, 0.25)
)

m <- lm(y ~ x, data = d) #linear model

d %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y) + #what to plot
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

without `method = "lm"` it draws a smoothed line.

As for the *Conf. interval (Obs 95%)* lines, it seems to me that's simply a quantile regression. In that case, you can use the *quantreg* package.

If you want to make it interactive, you can use the *plotly* package:

```
library(plotly)

p <- d %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image: zooming, selecting, and displaying]

================================================

P.S.

I am not completely sure this is what the figure you posted is showing (I guess so), but to add the quantile lines, I would just perform two quantile regressions (upper and lower) and then calculate the values of the quantile lines for your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantreg)

d <- tibble( #random stuff
  x = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  y = 0.25 * x + rnorm(100, 0, 0.25)
)

m <- lm(y ~ x, data = d) #linear model
# 95% quantile, two tailed
rq_low <- rq(y ~ x, data = d, tau = 0.025) #lower quantile
rq_high <- rq(y ~ x, data = d, tau = 0.975) #upper quantile

d %>% 
  mutate(low = rq_low$coefficients[1] + x * rq_low$coefficients[2],
         high = rq_high$coefficients[1] + x * rq_high$coefficients[2]) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x, y), method = "lm") +
  geom_line(aes(x, low), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(x, high), linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi E.B.! thank you so much for your response. You've helped me a lot! I'm a bit new to R so I just couldn't get the codes right, I had heard of ggplotly though. Somehow, I'm still struggling with this prediction or confidence band/lines. I tried the following: 

` geom_line(aes(y = lwr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(aes(y = upr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")`

But this doesn't work either. How would you recommend to use that package you proposed?

Comment: I get errors like this: 

`>     quantregLine(df.regsoft$w, df.regsoft$b, draw = TRUE)
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
>     p.rs %>% quantregLine(df.regsoft$w, df.regsoft$b, draw = TRUE)
Error in quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE,  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`